# How to restore Virtualbox machine from deleted machine's old directory?

Tags: virtualbox

Sorry that I had done a bad work:

Move Virtual machine's data directory form C drvive to D drive ,and change Virtualbox's global data directory to D drive too,and delete old machine item from virtubalbox GUI, and then try to build a new machines by just open the vbox machine file from new directory ,and I got error  code `VBOX_E_OBJECT_IN_USE (0x80BB000C)` ,which said  vhd `cannot be closed because it is still attached to 1 virtual machines`

I now know I can't export my old machines to `.ovf` file safely ,but there is no way back,

So how can I restore my machine from that old directory?

So appreciate that anybody can help me!

Host OS: Windows 7 64bit 
Guest OS: Windows XP 
Virtualbox :4.2.0 r80737

Here I post the content of that directory

```
├── Logs
│   ├── VBox.log
│   ├── VBox.log.1
│   ├── VBox.log.2
│   └── VBox.log.3
├── Snapshots
│   ├── 2012-11-14T09-00-56-385537700Z.sav
│   └── {fc5aa556-0a25-49e9-95a9-bbbb1a0f8e5d}.vhd
├── WinXP_32bit.vbox 
├── WinXP_32bit.vbox-prev
└── WinXP_32bit.vhd
```

and the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
** DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE.
** If you make changes to this file while any VirtualBox related application
** is running, your changes will be overwritten later, without taking effect.
** Use VBoxManage or the VirtualBox Manager GUI to make changes.
-->
<VirtualBox xmlns="http://www.innotek.de/VirtualBox-settings" version="1.12-windows">
  <Machine uuid="{2a61a1b6-ddd9-4814-a6d8-d2e93ca31854}" name="WinXP_32bit" OSType="WindowsXP" currentSnapshot="{001929de-293e-46dd-8a46-cf21532b61df}" snapshotFolder="Snapshots" lastStateChange="2014-06-12T10:35:45Z">
    <MediaRegistry>
      <HardDisks>
        <HardDisk uuid="{629650c4-6f74-43a0-a9d2-01c041493825}" location="WinXP_32bit.vhd" format="VHD" type="Normal"/>
      </HardDisks>
      <DVDImages>
        <Image uuid="{61abd4a1-84b4-4422-86f8-e0b1772be42d}" location="D:/zh-hans_windows_xp_professional_with_service_pack_3_x86_cd_vl_x14-74070.iso"/>
        <Image uuid="{fd3e6fa6-c065-4c35-be0c-0d6e827f5e16}" location="C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso"/>
      </DVDImages>
      <FloppyImages/>
    </MediaRegistry>
    <ExtraData>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastCloseAction" value="shutdown"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastGuestSizeHint" value="1600,793"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastNormalWindowPosition" value="8,30,1184,587,max"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastScaleWindowPosition" value="168,120,1144,536,max"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/MiniToolBarAlignment" value="top"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/SaveMountedAtRuntime" value="yes"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/ShowMiniToolBar" value="yes"/>
    </ExtraData>
    <Snapshot uuid="{001929de-293e-46dd-8a46-cf21532b61df}" name="&#x5907;&#x4EFD; 1" timeStamp="2012-11-14T09:00:56Z" stateFile="Snapshots/2012-11-14T09-00-56-385537700Z.sav">
      <Description>2012.1-2012.9</Description>
      <Hardware version="2">
        <CPU count="1" hotplug="false">
          <HardwareVirtEx enabled="true" exclusive="false"/>
          <HardwareVirtExNestedPaging enabled="true"/>
          <HardwareVirtExVPID enabled="true"/>
          <PAE enabled="false"/>
          <HardwareVirtExLargePages enabled="true"/>
          <HardwareVirtForce enabled="false"/>
        </CPU>
        <Memory RAMSize="192" PageFusion="false"/>
        <HID Pointing="USBTablet" Keyboard="PS2Keyboard"/>
        <HPET enabled="false"/>
        <Chipset type="PIIX3"/>
        <Boot>
          <Order position="1" device="Floppy"/>
          <Order position="2" device="DVD"/>
          <Order position="3" device="HardDisk"/>
          <Order position="4" device="None"/>
        </Boot>
        <Display VRAMSize="16" monitorCount="1" accelerate3D="false" accelerate2DVideo="false"/>
        <VideoRecording enabled="true" file="Test.webm" horzRes="640" vertRes="480"/>
        <RemoteDisplay enabled="false" authType="Null" authTimeout="5000"/>
        <BIOS>
          <ACPI enabled="true"/>
          <IOAPIC enabled="false"/>
          <Logo fadeIn="true" fadeOut="true" displayTime="0"/>
          <BootMenu mode="MessageAndMenu"/>
          <TimeOffset value="0"/>
          <PXEDebug enabled="false"/>
        </BIOS>
        <USBController enabled="true" enabledEhci="false"/>
        <Network>
          <Adapter slot="0" enabled="true" MACAddress="080027813054" cable="true" speed="0" type="Am79C973">
            <DisabledModes/>
            <NAT>
              <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
              <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
            </NAT>
          </Adapter>
          <Adapter slot="1" enabled="false" MACAddress="08002734BD4A" cable="true" speed="0" type="Am79C973">
            <DisabledModes>
              <NAT>
                <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
                <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
              </NAT>
            </DisabledModes>
          </Adapter>
          <Adapter slot="2" enabled="false" MACAddress="080027C62A1D" cable="true" speed="0" type="Am79C973">
            <DisabledModes>
              <NAT>
                <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
                <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
              </NAT>
            </DisabledModes>
          </Adapter>
          <Adapter slot="3" enabled="false" MACAddress="080027F8099B" cable="true" speed="0" type="Am79C973">
            <DisabledModes>
              <NAT>
                <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
                <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
              </NAT>
            </DisabledModes>
          </Adapter>
          <Adapter slot="4" enabled="false" MACAddress="08002776E217" cable="true" speed="0" type="Am79C973">
            <DisabledModes>
              <NAT>
                <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
                <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
              </NAT>
            </DisabledModes>
          </Adapter>
          <Adapter slot="5" enabled="false" MACAddress="0800272539A0" cable="true" speed="0" type="Am79C973">
            <DisabledModes>
              <NAT>
                <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
                <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
              </NAT>
            </DisabledModes>
          </Adapter>
          <Adapter slot="6" enabled="false" MACAddress="080027203F76" cable="true" speed="0" type="Am79C973">
            <DisabledModes>
              <NAT>
                <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
                <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
              </NAT>
            </DisabledModes>
          </Adapter>
          <Adapter slot="7" enabled="false" MACAddress="0800279F63C2" cable="true" speed="0" type="Am79C973">
            <DisabledModes>
              <NAT>
                <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
                <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
              </NAT>
            </DisabledModes>
          </Adapter>
        </Network>
        <UART>
          <Port slot="0" enabled="false" IOBase="0x3f8" IRQ="4" hostMode="Disconnected"/>
          <Port slot="1" enabled="false" IOBase="0x2f8" IRQ="3" hostMode="Disconnected"/>
        </UART>
        <LPT>
          <Port slot="0" enabled="false" IOBase="0x378" IRQ="7"/>
          <Port slot="1" enabled="false" IOBase="0x378" IRQ="7"/>
        </LPT>
        <AudioAdapter controller="AC97" driver="DirectSound" enabled="true"/>
        <RTC localOrUTC="local"/>
        <SharedFolders>
          <SharedFolder name="D_DRIVE" hostPath="D:\" writable="false" autoMount="true"/>
        </SharedFolders>
        <Clipboard mode="Disabled"/>
        <DragAndDrop mode="Disabled"/>
        <IO>
          <IoCache enabled="true" size="5"/>
          <BandwidthGroups/>
        </IO>
        <HostPci>
          <Devices/>
        </HostPci>
        <EmulatedUSB>
          <CardReader enabled="false"/>
        </EmulatedUSB>
        <Guest memoryBalloonSize="0"/>
        <GuestProperties>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/OS/Product" value="Windows XP Professional" timestamp="1352883316217341800" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/OS/Release" value="5.1.2600" timestamp="1352883316217841900" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/OS/Version" value="" timestamp="1352883316219342100" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/OS/ServicePack" value="3" timestamp="1352883316220342200" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Version" value="4.2.0" timestamp="1352883316220842300" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/VersionExt" value="4.2.0" timestamp="1352883316221342300" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Revision" value="80737" timestamp="1352883316221842400" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/InstallDir" value="C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox Guest Additions" timestamp="1352883316222342500" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxControl.exe" value="4.2.0r80737" timestamp="1352883316223342600" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxHook.dll" value="4.2.0r80737" timestamp="1352883316224342700" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxDisp.dll" value="4.2.0r80737" timestamp="1352883316224842800" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxMRXNP.dll" value="4.2.0r80737" timestamp="1352883316225842900" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxService.exe" value="4.2.0r80737" timestamp="1352883316226343000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxTray.exe" value="4.2.0r80737" timestamp="1352883316226843000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxGINA.dll" value="-" timestamp="1352883316242345000" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxCredProv.dll" value="-" timestamp="1352883316246345500" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxOGLarrayspu.dll" value="4.2.0r80737" timestamp="1352883316249345900" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxOGLcrutil.dll" value="4.2.0r80737" timestamp="1352883316249845900" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxOGLerrorspu.dll" value="4.2.0r80737" timestamp="1352883316250846100" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxOGLpackspu.dll" value="4.2.0r80737" timestamp="1352883316251346100" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxOGLpassthroughspu.dll" value="4.2.0r80737" timestamp="1352883316251846200" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxOGLfeedbackspu.dll" value="4.2.0r80737" timestamp="1352883316252846300" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxOGL.dll" value="4.2.0r80737" timestamp="1352883316253346400" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxGuest.sys" value="4.2.0r80737" timestamp="1352883316254346500" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxMouse.sys" value="4.2.0r80737" timestamp="1352883316255346600" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxSF.sys" value="4.2.0r80737" timestamp="1352883316256346800" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxVideo.sys" value="4.2.0r80737" timestamp="1352883316256846800" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/V4/IP" value="10.0.2.15" timestamp="1352883318701157200" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/V4/Broadcast" value="255.255.255.255" timestamp="1352883318702157300" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/V4/Netmask" value="255.255.255.0" timestamp="1352883318702657400" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/Status" value="Up" timestamp="1352883318703157500" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/MAC" value="080027813054" timestamp="1352883318704157600" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/HostVerLastChecked" value="4.2.0" timestamp="1352883329123980800" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/HostInfo/GUI/LanguageID" value="zh_CN" timestamp="1352883621053551100" flags=""/>
          <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/Count" value="1" timestamp="1352883638950323700" flags=""/>
        </GuestProperties>
      </Hardware>
      <StorageControllers>
        <StorageController name="IDE &#x63A7;&#x5236;&#x5668;" type="PIIX4" PortCount="2" useHostIOCache="true" Bootable="true">
          <AttachedDevice type="HardDisk" port="0" device="0">
            <Image uuid="{629650c4-6f74-43a0-a9d2-01c041493825}"/>
          </AttachedDevice>
          <AttachedDevice passthrough="false" type="DVD" port="1" device="0">
            <Image uuid="{fd3e6fa6-c065-4c35-be0c-0d6e827f5e16}"/>
          </AttachedDevice>
        </StorageController>
      </StorageControllers>
    </Snapshot>
    <Hardware version="2">
      <CPU count="1" hotplug="false">
        <HardwareVirtEx enabled="true" exclusive="false"/>
        <HardwareVirtExNestedPaging enabled="true"/>
        <HardwareVirtExVPID enabled="true"/>
        <PAE enabled="false"/>
        <HardwareVirtExLargePages enabled="true"/>
        <HardwareVirtForce enabled="false"/>
      </CPU>
      <Memory RAMSize="512" PageFusion="false"/>
      <HID Pointing="USBTablet" Keyboard="PS2Keyboard"/>
      <HPET enabled="false"/>
      <Chipset type="PIIX3"/>
      <Boot>
        <Order position="1" device="DVD"/>
        <Order position="2" device="HardDisk"/>
        <Order position="3" device="None"/>
        <Order position="4" device="None"/>
      </Boot>
      <Display VRAMSize="16" monitorCount="1" accelerate3D="false" accelerate2DVideo="false"/>
      <VideoRecording enabled="true" file="Test.webm" horzRes="640" vertRes="480"/>
      <RemoteDisplay enabled="false" authType="Null" authTimeout="5000"/>
      <BIOS>
        <ACPI enabled="true"/>
        <IOAPIC enabled="false"/>
        <Logo fadeIn="true" fadeOut="true" displayTime="0"/>
        <BootMenu mode="MessageAndMenu"/>
        <TimeOffset value="0"/>
        <PXEDebug enabled="false"/>
      </BIOS>
      <USBController enabled="true" enabledEhci="false"/>
      <Network>
        <Adapter slot="0" enabled="true" MACAddress="080027813054" cable="true" speed="0" type="Am79C973">
          <DisabledModes>
            <NAT>
              <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
              <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
            </NAT>
          </DisabledModes>
          <BridgedInterface name="Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller"/>
        </Adapter>
        <Adapter slot="1" enabled="false" MACAddress="08002734BD4A" cable="true" speed="0" type="Am79C973">
          <DisabledModes>
            <NAT>
              <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
              <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
            </NAT>
          </DisabledModes>
        </Adapter>
        <Adapter slot="2" enabled="false" MACAddress="080027C62A1D" cable="true" speed="0" type="Am79C973">
          <DisabledModes>
            <NAT>
              <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
              <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
            </NAT>
          </DisabledModes>
        </Adapter>
        <Adapter slot="3" enabled="false" MACAddress="080027F8099B" cable="true" speed="0" type="Am79C973">
          <DisabledModes>
            <NAT>
              <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
              <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
            </NAT>
          </DisabledModes>
        </Adapter>
        <Adapter slot="4" enabled="false" MACAddress="08002776E217" cable="true" speed="0" type="Am79C973">
          <DisabledModes>
            <NAT>
              <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
              <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
            </NAT>
          </DisabledModes>
        </Adapter>
        <Adapter slot="5" enabled="false" MACAddress="0800272539A0" cable="true" speed="0" type="Am79C973">
          <DisabledModes>
            <NAT>
              <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
              <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
            </NAT>
          </DisabledModes>
        </Adapter>
        <Adapter slot="6" enabled="false" MACAddress="080027203F76" cable="true" speed="0" type="Am79C973">
          <DisabledModes>
            <NAT>
              <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
              <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
            </NAT>
          </DisabledModes>
        </Adapter>
        <Adapter slot="7" enabled="false" MACAddress="0800279F63C2" cable="true" speed="0" type="Am79C973">
          <DisabledModes>
            <NAT>
              <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
              <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
            </NAT>
          </DisabledModes>
        </Adapter>
      </Network>
      <UART>
        <Port slot="0" enabled="false" IOBase="0x3f8" IRQ="4" hostMode="Disconnected"/>
        <Port slot="1" enabled="false" IOBase="0x2f8" IRQ="3" hostMode="Disconnected"/>
      </UART>
      <LPT>
        <Port slot="0" enabled="false" IOBase="0x378" IRQ="7"/>
        <Port slot="1" enabled="false" IOBase="0x378" IRQ="7"/>
      </LPT>
      <AudioAdapter controller="AC97" driver="DirectSound" enabled="true"/>
      <RTC localOrUTC="local"/>
      <SharedFolders>
        <SharedFolder name="D_DRIVE" hostPath="D:\" writable="true" autoMount="true"/>
      </SharedFolders>
      <Clipboard mode="Bidirectional"/>
      <DragAndDrop mode="Disabled"/>
      <IO>
        <IoCache enabled="true" size="5"/>
        <BandwidthGroups/>
      </IO>
      <HostPci>
        <Devices/>
      </HostPci>
      <EmulatedUSB>
        <CardReader enabled="false"/>
      </EmulatedUSB>
      <Guest memoryBalloonSize="0"/>
      <GuestProperties>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/HostInfo/GUI/LanguageID" value="zh_CN" timestamp="1402569193737395000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/OS/Product" value="Windows XP Professional" timestamp="1402569209339876300" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/OS/Release" value="5.1.2600" timestamp="1402569209340876400" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/OS/Version" value="" timestamp="1402569209342876700" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/OS/ServicePack" value="3" timestamp="1402569209343376700" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Version" value="4.2.0" timestamp="1402569209343876800" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/VersionExt" value="4.2.0" timestamp="1402569209344376900" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Revision" value="80737" timestamp="1402569209345377000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/InstallDir" value="C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox Guest Additions" timestamp="1402569209345877100" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxControl.exe" value="4.2.0r80737" timestamp="1402569209347377300" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxHook.dll" value="4.2.0r80737" timestamp="1402569209348877400" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxDisp.dll" value="4.2.0r80737" timestamp="1402569209349377500" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxMRXNP.dll" value="4.2.0r80737" timestamp="1402569209350877700" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxService.exe" value="4.2.0r80737" timestamp="1402569209351377800" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxTray.exe" value="4.2.0r80737" timestamp="1402569209353378000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxGINA.dll" value="-" timestamp="1402569209369880100" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxCredProv.dll" value="-" timestamp="1402569209374380700" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxOGLarrayspu.dll" value="4.2.0r80737" timestamp="1402569209375380800" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxOGLcrutil.dll" value="4.2.0r80737" timestamp="1402569209376881000" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxOGLerrorspu.dll" value="4.2.0r80737" timestamp="1402569209379881400" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxOGLpackspu.dll" value="4.2.0r80737" timestamp="1402569209381881600" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxOGLpassthroughspu.dll" value="4.2.0r80737" timestamp="1402569209383881900" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxOGLfeedbackspu.dll" value="4.2.0r80737" timestamp="1402569209385382100" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxOGL.dll" value="4.2.0r80737" timestamp="1402569209386382200" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxGuest.sys" value="4.2.0r80737" timestamp="1402569209387382300" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxMouse.sys" value="4.2.0r80737" timestamp="1402569209388382500" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxSF.sys" value="4.2.0r80737" timestamp="1402569209389382600" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Components/VBoxVideo.sys" value="4.2.0r80737" timestamp="1402569209390382700" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/HostVerLastChecked" value="4.2.0" timestamp="1402569226298029700" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/OS/LoggedInUsersList" value="" timestamp="1402569337281122800" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/V4/IP" value="" timestamp="1402569340928085900" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/MAC" value="" timestamp="1402569340939587300" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/V4/Netmask" value="" timestamp="1402569340940087400" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/Status" value="" timestamp="1402569340940587500" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/V4/Broadcast" value="" timestamp="1402569340941087500" flags=""/>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/Count" value="" timestamp="1402569340941587600" flags=""/>
      </GuestProperties>
    </Hardware>
    <StorageControllers>
      <StorageController name="IDE &#x63A7;&#x5236;&#x5668;" type="PIIX4" PortCount="2" useHostIOCache="true" Bootable="true">
        <AttachedDevice type="HardDisk" port="0" device="0">
          <Image uuid="{fc5aa556-0a25-49e9-95a9-bbbb1a0f8e5d}"/>
        </AttachedDevice>
        <AttachedDevice passthrough="false" type="DVD" port="1" device="0">
          <Image uuid="{fd3e6fa6-c065-4c35-be0c-0d6e827f5e16}"/>
        </AttachedDevice>
      </StorageController>
    </StorageControllers>
  </Machine>
</VirtualBox>

  </GuestProperties>
</Hardware>
<StorageControllers>
  <StorageController name="IDE &#x63A7;&#x5236;&#x5668;" type="PIIX4" PortCount="2" useHostIOCache="true" Bootable="true">
    <AttachedDevice type="HardDisk" port="0" device="0">
      <Image uuid="{fc5aa556-0a25-49e9-95a9-bbbb1a0f8e5d}"/>
    </AttachedDevice>
    <AttachedDevice passthrough="false" type="DVD" port="1" device="0">
      <Image uuid="{fd3e6fa6-c065-4c35-be0c-0d6e827f5e16}"/>
    </AttachedDevice>
  </StorageController>
</StorageControllers>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this article http://www.treshna.com/rebuilding-virtualbox-with-missing-vdi-snapshots/ and done what as the article guide

```
➜  WinXP_32bit $ VBoxManage clonehd Snapshots/\{fc5aa556-0a25-49e9-95a9-bbbb1a0f8e5d\}.vhd ../Newhd.vdi
VBoxManage: error: Parent medium with UUID {629650c4-6f74-43a0-a9d2-01c041493825} of the medium '/Users/shiangro/Downloads/WinXP_32bit/Snapshots/{fc5aa556-0a25-49e9-95a9-bbbb1a0f8e5d}.v
hd' is not found in the media registry ('/Users/shiangro/Library/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml')
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component Medium, interface IMedium, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "OpenMedium(Bstr(pszFilenameOrUuid).raw(), enmDevType, enmAccessMode, fForceNewUuidOnOpen, pMedium.asOutParam())" at line 220 of file VBoxManageDisk.cpp
```

As the error said there was no an item in `VirtualBox.xml` I had a trick to sovled this :

build a new machine and select that Parent medium with UUID {629650c4-6f74-43a0-a9d2-01c041493825} (which is the parent disk of that snapshot disk) as the hard disk for the new machine ,then a new item will be added in `VirtualBox.xml`, then do it again:

```
➜  WinXP_32bit  VBoxManage clonehd Snapshots/\{fc5aa556-0a25-49e9-95a9-bbbb1a0f8e5d\}.vhd ../Newclonehd.vdi
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Clone hard disk created in format 'VHD'. UUID: 7c93af5f-75fe-4ce1-96bd-efbcfbce450e
```

The above command will merge the snapshot vhd and it's parent disk to a new vdi disk.

Finally , I use this new created vdi as the new disk for that machine and that works, and my data is back!

haha!